# gridview pageindex in update panel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, indexing, updatepanel, page-index-changed

I have a gridview inside an updatepanel ,on first click the page index is changing but later clicks the page indexes are not changing. but the events are triggering when click.
this is how i bind data.

```
protected void gvPurchaseDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvPurchaseDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DetailsGridBind();
}

public void DetailsGridBind()
{

    DataSet dsInvoice = ObjDetail.GetPurchaseDetails();
    DataTable dtInvoice = dsInvoice.Tables[0];
    gvPurchaseDetails.DataSource = dtInvoice;
    gvPurchaseDetails.DataBind();     
}
```

Comment: please share some code!

Comment: like sine said...post the code...for your `pageindexchanging` event and your `pageload` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true"` for your `GridView`

By default its set to `false`

Also in the code behind update your `UpdatePanel`

```
protected void gvPurchaseDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvPurchaseDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DetailsGridBind();

    yourUpdatePanelId.Update();   // add this line of code was well
}
```

Comment: can you post ur updated code in the question. also post the markup of gridview.

Comment: There was two update panels in the page .. when i removed and made it one now my code works fine..sorry for wasting ur time